AVI file with ADPCM Format not playing audio
I have an avi video that won't play sound. The video plays normally.
I checked its media info and it's showing the below.
Media Info Sreenshot
ID:1
Format:ADPCM
Codec ID: 11
Codec ID/Hint: Intel
Duration: 1 min 13 s
Bit Rate mode: Constant
Bit Rate: 176.4 kb/s
Channel (s): 1 channel
Sampling rate: 44.1 KHz
Bit depth: 4 bits
Stream size: 1.56 MiB(4%)
Interleave, duration: 47 ms (1.41 video frame)
Please let me know what other information you would need to help me fix the audio. As you can tell i am not very knowledgeable in this area, so I would really appreciate your help and guidance.
Thanks!

What OS and what software are you using to play the media? Does it play sound on a different device?

Following @music2myear request -- have you tried VLC, available for many OS's?
